# Relationship of classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have two classes, i want to put instances of a class Bear in a list from class Cave like below, but that code doesn't works. Should classes be in relationship? How can I change code?

```
class Bear
{
    public Bear(int age, string name)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

class Cave
{
    List<Bear> cave = new List<Bear>();
    cave.Add(new Bear(16, "Johnny"));
    cave.Add(new Bear(10,"Herman"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting any errors, please post them. You can't put code like that directly in the class. All executable code must be inside a method. Move the code in your Cave class into a method:

```
class Bear
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bear(int age, string name)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

class Cave
{
    List<Bear> cave = new List<Bear>();

    public Cave()
    {
        cave.Add(new Bear(16, "Johnny"));
        cave.Add(new Bear(10,"Herman"));
    }
}
```

Comment: May want to also add definitions for Bear.Age and Bear.Name?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - Yes, good catch.  I copied the code from the OP.

Comment: "All executable code must be inside a method." That's not entirely accurate - change the word `method` to `member` - a method, a property, a constructor, or an indexer - and you have a winner.